# Python: NameError: name 'ma_formula' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to figure out why I can't get the defined function working. I'm pretty new at python, but feel like it should be working as is.

```
import math
import random
answer = 0 
# i *think* this means that the value of the variable answer in the function
# ma_formula() can be used outside the function once the function is done right?
def my_forumla():
    answer = a * b * c;

a = math.pi;
b = random.randint(2,288);
c = eval(input("Enter your number here: \n"));
print(str(a) + ", " + str(b) + ", " + str(c)) 
my_formula();
print(answer);
```

Comment: After you correct the spelling, you'll notice that `answer` is not set right where you print it. You should replace the line before with `answer = my_formula()`. And please, please remove those ugly `;` - they are not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *misspelled* your function name:

```
def my_forumla():
```

should be:

```
def my_formula():
```

You transposed the `u` and `m`.

You did so again in your question title and comment, where you spelled `ma_formula` (note the `a` at the start instead of a `y`).

Note that `answer` is a local variable in `my_formula()` and won't be accessible outside of the function. Use `return` to return it instead and assign the returned value or print it directly. Give your function *parameters* too, that is a better practice than to treat `a`, `b` and `c` as globals:

```
def my_forumla(a, b, c):
    return a * b * c;

answer = my_formula(a, b, c)
print(answer)
```

Comment: omg - i'm an idiot. Sorry, thought it would stupid to have ma_forumula so I quickly renamed it to my_formula for posting purposes. Clearly didn't change it in the comments though. The misspelling came from renaming quickly. Yeah - still the "not defined thing" was the issue.

Comment: ok - so I guess I misunderstood about defining a variable. I thought that if you defined it outside of a function that if used within the function it would still store the information. Thanks!